# Gradients do not exist for variables in custom layers in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I am trying to build a custom 1D convolution layer in TensorFlow. I have checked that the layer does what is supposed to do. However when I insert it in a sequential Keras model I get that WARNING that Gradients do not exists for variables in the custom layer.

Can you please explain why this happens and how I can fix it?

This is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


class customC1DLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filter_size = 1, activation = None ,**kwargs):
        super(customC1DLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filter_size = filter_size
        self.activation = tf.keras.activations.get(activation)
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.filter = self.add_weight('filter', shape=[self.filter_size, ], trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)

        self.padding = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(shape=[input_shape[-1] - self.filter_size, ], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=False)
        padded_filter = tf.concat([self.filter, self.padding], axis=0)
        col = tf.concat([padded_filter[:1], tf.zeros_like(padded_filter[1:])], axis=0)
        self.augmented_filter = tf.linalg.LinearOperatorToeplitz(padded_filter, col).to_dense()
     
    def call(self, inputs):
        outputs = tf.transpose(tf.matmul(self.augmented_filter, inputs, transpose_b=True))
        if self.activation is not None:
            outputs = self.activation(outputs)
        return outputs
```

To explain the code, in the method build I initialize some weights for example [a b c] and then the augmented_filter is just the circulant matrix [[a b c 0 0], [0 a b c 0], [0 0 a b c]]

I know that such mistakes can occur when non differentiable functions are used. However, in this case I am only using matrix operation which should differentiable, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, in the call function, there is no path from the `augmented_filter` to `padding` -- I presume you want the gradients for the latter. As it stands, the variable is effectively not used, so no gradients can be computed. You will need to do this transformation within `call`:

```
class customC1DLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filter_size = 1, activation = None ,**kwargs):
        super(customC1DLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filter_size = filter_size
        self.activation = tf.keras.activations.get(activation)
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.filter = self.add_weight('filter', shape=[self.filter_size, ], trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)

        self.padding = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(shape=[input_shape[-1] - self.filter_size, ], dtype=tf.float32), trainable=False)
     
    def call(self, inputs):

        padded_filter = tf.concat([self.filter, self.padding], axis=0)
        col = tf.concat([padded_filter[:1], tf.zeros_like(padded_filter[1:])], axis=0)
        augmented_filter = tf.linalg.LinearOperatorToeplitz(padded_filter, col).to_dense()
        outputs = tf.transpose(tf.matmul(augmented_filter, inputs, transpose_b=True))
        if self.activation is not None:
            outputs = self.activation(outputs)
        return outputs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestion solves the problem. However, I still find it a bit inconvenient to construct the augmented filter for each call, that is why I constructed in the build function. Basically, the augmented filter is just a circulant matrix where the first row is just some trainable weights and zeros. So I was wondering if it is possible to compute this circulant matrix in the build function and still be able to compute Gradients with respect to the trainable weights.